# "Ficus elasticus" losing leaves

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-care, leaves, ficus

I've had this *Ficus* for 3 months now. It started dropping the bottom leaves first, but as there was nothing else wrong and the bottom stem was hardening I assumed it's becoming more like a tree.

Last two times I've watered it, it would react badly, within a few days damage would be visible on the leaves.
Since last watering, one leaf started fading to yellow and dropped. I see two more leaves with similar fading.

I'm watering it once in two weeks and check for water overflow in the outer pot about an hour after watering.

Any ideas on what may be wrong?

[image: fallen leaf]

[image: damage in early stage]

[image: different leaf damage]

[image: whole plant]

Comment: Good question and good illustrations; if could include overall height, leaf size, stem diameter, current watering amount, current nutrient type & amount & frequency, hours of sunlight per day, hours of diffused light per day, average daytime temperature, average night time temperature, average humidity, size of container, soil, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Your rubber tree has signs of root rot. The soil is too damp for too long, which is either caused by too frequent watering (overwatering) or poor drainage in the soil (or the combination of both).

To get back to a healthy situation I suggest you stop watering for a while, until you are sure the soil is completely dry. If you say you water it every 2 weeks, look in 3 weeks if the soil is dry or still damp.